# Slow scroll speed down

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

Ok, so I can't find anything about this.

I know it is horrible to change the scroll speed of a site, but I need to do this for a site which is more a game than a site.

Can someone tell me how to slow down de scrollspeed? Jquery or css?

EDIT: I want to change the scrollspeed whem people scroll with the mouse wheel.

Comment: You mean when e.g. scroll down with mousewheel?

Comment: check out this plugin http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: What code have you tried? Anything you researched about? Where's your issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**NiceScroll**](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com) Plugin

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

);
```

Comment: which jQuery version?

Comment: Do not use NiceScroll, it doesn't work on iOS.

Answer (score 11):

Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/NFk2L/ , you can set time and distance!

**JS code**

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000;
    var distance = 300;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}
```

```js
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
  var delta = 0;
  if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
  else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

  handle(delta);
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
  var time = 1000;
  var distance = 300;

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
  }, time);
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #CCF;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, when i tried your demo it went weird when i scrolled...too slow then very quick with lag.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed

[Demo](http://code.nath.co/scrollSpeed)

You can add the value speed in this code

Answer (score -10):

Just go to the windows mouse properties in control panel there you can set the amount of pages to slide through with one scroll.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. You mean like changing the settings of my computer? Because if that is what you are saying then it wouldn't work because the scrollspeed should be different on every computer;)

Comment: OP needs this to be controllable on website