# How to slow down scrolling speed with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

When I scroll some litlle div with many elements, my mouse scrolling is too fast so I can't see few elements.

Comment: Check your mouse scroll settings first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slow scroll speed down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950450/slow-scroll-speed-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll speed can't be altered as they are System configurations and Javascript shouldn't be allowed to alter a user's own settings.

But there are a lot of jquery custom scrollbars that you can use, which offer an option to change the scroll speed.
Examples: **mCustomScrollbar, jquery slimscroll etc**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NiceScroll](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/) plugin with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

);
```

Or [jQuery.scrollSpeed](https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed) plugin.