# Slow down horizontal scrolling of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container with 3 lines of text, Each line exceeds the width of that container, So there is a horizontal scroll bar, But I hide it, I want to make the scrolling slower for this element only.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ehp3qnty/576/

Here is the code:

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  /* maximum width of scrollbar */
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* maximum width of scrollbar */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- .child -->
</div>
<!-- .parent -->
```

How to make is slower?

I need a pure CSS/JS solution without any plugin/library.

Comment: This is not possible without any plugin.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017692/how-to-slow-down-scrolling-speed-with-javascript)

Comment: How is the user scrolling it? Using `shift+scroll`?

Comment: @vrugtehagel, It's for small devices(mobiles), Try to press keyboard arrows or use responsiveness mode and swipe the element

Comment: In that case I think it's browser dependent. You'd have to manually do the cases you want to support (like mimicking swiping by manually setting it's position based on the `touchmove` data, or manually setting the `margin-left` or `left` property when pressing the arrow keys).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#your_div').hScroll(100); // You can pass (optionally) scrolling amount
});
Here goes the upgraded plugin jquery.hscroll.js:

jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.hScroll = function (amount) {
        amount = amount || 120;
        $(this).bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", function (event) {
            var oEvent = event.originalEvent, 
                direction = oEvent.detail ? oEvent.detail * -amount : oEvent.wheelDelta, 
                position = $(this).scrollLeft();
            position += direction > 0 ? -amount : amount;
            $(this).scrollLeft(position);
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: Um, jQuery is a plugin, and he asked specifically for an answer in pure JS (or CSS)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are a lot of ways to achieve this. One simple way is make a scroll longer, and set the position of content relative to the new scroll.

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let `w` is a container width and `s` is a content width (or initial scroll width).

If I want to make a scroll `f` times slower, I have to make a scroll `f` times longer. The scroll width will be `s * f`.

At the end of scroll, the `scrollLeft` will be `s * f - w`.  And the left of content must be `s * f - s`.

So the ratio will be `(s * f - s) / (s * f - w)`.

JavaScript:

```
let f = 5
let s = container.scrollWidth

container.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let w = container.offsetWidth
  let r = (s * f - s) / (s * f - w)
  let x = container.scrollLeft
  content.style.transform = `translateX(${x * r}px)`
})
```

This may not be a perfect solution but I hope this help.

See live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/stnz0ey5/).