# Slow down scrolling speed javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-scrolling

I would like to slow down the scrolling speed of a website to better control what the user sees. I am currently using the following function..

Since this triggers an Intervention in Chrome, and it creates shaky behaviour of the UI, it does not make any sense to use it..

Is there anyone who knows an alternative to this? I prefer to avoid adding extra libraries because of the complexity this adds to the end product, but if there is no other option..

```
// slows down scrolling speed 
// still get an intervention, maybe put in on Stackoverflow 
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('wheel', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    //if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000;
    var distance = 400;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}
```

Comment: seems like its not possible without a certain JQuery plugin called "NiceScroll", check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950450/slow-scroll-speed-down

Comment: I've written a [relatively small plugin](http://ataredo.com/morphology/lucidscroll/) exactly for this kind of thing.

Comment: I will check it out! Thanks both!

Comment: @A.A. it is definitely possible without a jQuery plugin. All jQuery and its plugins do is make things easier.

Comment: @YongQuan you will have to tweak every little scroll movement in JS, it is definetly possible to do it, everything is, but i wont be portable and might have problems with other resolutions. Check out the answers on equal questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017692/how-to-slow-down-scrolling-speed-with-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950450/slow-scroll-speed-down all recommend highly to use a plugin

Comment: @A.A. that's what I meant. They only make things easier. You said "not possible" in a previous comment, which is not true. I am only pointing this out for beginners to avoid misinformation.

Comment: NiceScroll seems to mainly focus on the appearance of the scrollbar, not on the behaviour.. Shikkediel, I tested your plugin but I cannot get it to work..

Comment: @NielsVanwingh Yes it does affect scroling speed if intented, therefore check out https://carlofontanos.com/how-to-use-nicescroll-js/ for all options, in your case it would be  `$("html").niceScroll({...., scrollspeed: 60});` (60 is default value you can change it lower or higher as you wish)