# How can I increase the scrollspeed of the div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a sort of parallax webdesign. My question is, if someone knows how I can make the red div move faster. I think its in the formule but dont know sure. Maybe someone knows?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/PvVdq/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

    var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

    $horizontal.css({
        'left': position
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slow scroll speed down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950450/slow-scroll-speed-down)

Comment: var position = (scrollPercent * 3 *($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about this. When I tried this one, it speeds up the movement of the red div

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

    var position = (scrollPercent * 10 * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

    $horizontal.css({
        'left': position
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I am editing it now into my own website. But then it goes to quick.

Comment: Just lessen the 10. I started from 1 and slowly tested it all the way to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo need to play with your scrollPercent , if you want it go faster :

```
    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c) * 2);//twice fatser
```

or even faster :

```
    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c) * 3);//3 times fatser
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PvVdq/1448/